# Bizarre C++ compiler problem

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```
typedef istream_iterator<string> isi;

// (1)
vector<string> lineas(isi(cin), isi());

// (2)
//vector<string> lineas;
//copy(isi(cin), isi(), back_inserter(lineas));

typedef vector<string>::iterator vci;
for (vci it = lineas.begin(); it != lineas.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
```

However, I get the error while compiling:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:16: error: request for member 'begin' in 'lineas', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >(main(int, char**)::isi, main(int, char**)::isi (*)())'
test.cpp:16: error: request for member 'end' in 'lineas', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >(main(int, char**)::isi, main(int, char**)::isi (*)())'
```

However, if I replace (1) by (2), it compiles.

I'm using g++ 4.4.0

What's wrong?

Comment: Do not attempt to format your code using HTML tags - use the 1010 button above the text entry area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler and you are interpreting this line differently:

```
vector<string> lineas( isi(cin), isi() );
```

For you it is defining and initializing a variable `lineas` of type `vector<string>` with the constructor that takes two iterators.

For the compiler you are defining a function `lineas` returning a `vector<string>` and taking two arguments the first of which  is an `isi`and the second of which is a function taking no arguments and returning an `isi`... With time you will get used to reading compiler errors and what it is reading from your code.

The simplest solution is adding an extra pair of parenthesis:

```
vector<string> lineas( (isi(cin)), isi() );
```

You can find a longer explanation in the C++ FAQ Lite [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.19).

Comment: "the first of which is a function itself..." <- you meant "the second of which" :) The first is taking an "isi".

Comment: Right... corrected. I tend to be lazy reading error messages. Once I know what the problem and the solution are I tend to turn the neurons off :)

Comment: I think `isi(cin>>skipws())` works equally well - or `isi(cin>>noskipws())` if that's what you really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First line according to C++ rules stating that "everything what's possible will be parsed as a declaration will be passed as a declaration" so in your example you are declaring a fnc named lineas which takes first argument::
isi(cin),
of type isi called cin and second argument:
isi() 
pointer to function not taking any arguments and returning object of type isi. Your function returns vector of strings as a result;